# Retrieving value (not display item) of DropDown

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am filling DropDown dynamically using AJAX. The DropDown code looks like this:

```
<select class="element select medium" id="inDistrict" name="inDistrict" onclick="MakeRequest('divDistrict', 'inDistrict', 'SELECT * FROM districtmaster');" onchange="alert(document.getElementByID('inDistrict').value);"> 
    <option value="Select" selected="Select">Select</option>
</select>
```

Another file that executes on AJAX request contains following code:

```
<?php
    require("dbconnection.php");
    require("dbaccess.php");

    $dropdownControlName = $_GET['DropDownControlName'];
    $query = $_GET['SqlQuery'];
    dbconnection::OpenConnection();
    $result = dbaccess::GetRows($query);
?>
<select name="<?php echo $dropdownControlName; ?>">
<option>Select from the list</option>
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>
    <option value="<?= $row[0] ?>"><?= $row[1] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Everything works fine and the DropDowns also get filled, except that I am not following how to pick the value of the Option. In the above code you can see that I am using row[0] as value and row[1] as the display item. I want to pick the row[0] value whenever a user selects any row[1] display item.

In the first code above, you can see that I added an onchange event and there is just an alert box. But it is not executing. How to pick the row[0] value and why onchange event is not firing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onchange` doesn't fire in response to DOM manipulation of the selected value.  You can fire it manually with some simple javascript:

```
var inDistrict = document.getElementById('inDistrict');
if (inDistrict.onchange)
  inDistrict.onchange();
```

If you're using jQuery, it's even easier:

```
$('#inDistrict').change();
```

Since it looks like you're replacing the entire dropdownlist with your ajax request, just throw some of that javascript in there to fire the change event when it's done populating, and you should be good to go.

Comment: And how to pick the row[0] i.e., the value of the display item?

Comment: It's just the "value" property of the selected option.  `mydropdown.options[mydropdown.selectedIndex].value`

Answer (score 2):

Wrong case usage in your onchage event line:

```
document.getElementByID
```

Correct:

```
document.getElementById
```

**Note** that rather than using above; you can alert dropdown value like this too:

```
onchange="alert(this.value);"
```

**Then for dropdown:**

If you add **[ ]** to the names of elements, they become array eg:

```
<select name="myselect[]">
```

Now from php you can access each of its element like this:
(assuming that you post method in the form)

```
echo $_POST['myselect'][0]; // this prints first item value
echo $_POST['myselect'][1]; // this prints second item value
echo $_POST['myselect'][2]; // this prints third item value
//and so on...
```

Comment: Actually I wrote correctly in my original file, while editing the post it might have changed. Please ignore.

Comment: When the DropDown is being filled dynamically, naming it as an array, how to get the size of the array?

Comment: i have just given an example, you could use ajax there for that, and also send back the size of it by sending back it in ajax response. how to count count($_POST['myselect'])